# How can I theme the markup for the labels in a set of radio options on a specific form item?

Tags: 8, theming, forms

Given this form item defined in a custom module;

```
$form['my_items'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Items'),
  '#options' => $optionsSet // array of options pulled from a data source
];
```

How can I modify the label of each option to include a small image to the right of the text? In my case, the image is stored in the same dataset alongside each label.

I'm going to guess this has something to do with adding a '#theme' attribute, but I haven't been able to determine the entire process for setting that up.

Comment: Unfortunately, adding images to select options is a tricky thing. See [How to add images in select list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list)

Comment: Never done this before. Prob you'll have to use [template_preprocess_select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list) and create a new variable for the URL. Then copy to your theme's template and modify [select.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21select.html.twig/8.2.x) add the `style="background-image:url(image.png)` part

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, that is tricky, but this isn't about select elements — it's about a set of radios.

Comment: Ah! then I think my answer below might work, not tested. But Obviously it's hard coded, so all you gotta do is make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to massage the `$optionsSet` array so it's structured like this:

```
$optionsSet = [
  'option1' => '<img scr="../images/option1.jpg"/>option 1',
  'option2' => '<img scr="../images/option2.jpg"/>option 2',
];

$form['my_items'] = [
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#title' => $this->t('Items'),
  '#options' => $optionsSet,
];
```